# Align Controls in WPF in run-time like visual studio

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to develop an application which gives to user the ability to edit controls(Button, TextBox etc.)at run time,  it should work like visual studio, with control's align, resize etc), can somebody tell me how should I implement it?
any idea can help..
Thank you.

Comment: @Asaf maimon Did my answer provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Every control has properties like Width, Height, and afaik Left or Top (could be a bit different name, don't have VS around here). When you set them the controls will be changed on the fly.